# Cannot put together regex and list results

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am fairly new to regular expressions so apologies if this seems too generic a question.

Scenario:

I have a set of files in which I have isolated a specific pattern, say [mainpattern]. In each occurence of this pattern, [mainpattern] is preceded by various [subpattern] occurences with a right arrow before it and a dot after it:

> cat *.txt | grep "mainpattern"

... [>][subpattern1][.][mainpattern]...

... [>][subpattern2][.][mainpattern]...

...

... [>][subpatternN][.][mainpattern]...

I am basically trying to produce an output where all subpatterns are uniquely listed (no duplicates). Any ideas? I have not been able to figure out how to code "get me the preceding *word* from the grep output".

Many thanks

Comment: Try `cat *.txt | grep -oP '(?<=[.])subpattern(?=[.]mainpattern)'`, but I am not sure it will address the duplicate issue.

Comment: Just gave it a try (it does not work) but I think I should be specific about the fact that I know the [mainpattern] part, but the [subpattern] occurences are always random and unknown *a priori* ... The idea is to list these randomly generated sequences.

Comment: So, you only know that the `subpattern` is anything but a dot? Try `'(?<=[.])[^.]*(?=[.]mainpattern)'`

Comment: Almost there! Now I get something like 



[some stuff which is not relevant to me]>subpattern1

[some stuff which is not relevant to me]>subpattern2

[some stuff which is not relevant to me]>subpattern3



etc.

So the delimiting caracter that isolates the subpattern is actually ">".

What is the logic behind the regex?

Comment: So, try `grep -oP '(?<=>)[^>.]*(?=[.]mainpattern)'`

Comment: It works! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a  PCRE style regex `(?<=>)[^>.]*(?=[.]mainpattern)` with `-oP` options (`P` for PCRE and `o` for output match mode):

```
grep -oP '(?<=>)[^>.]*(?=[.]mainpattern)'
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=>)` - a position in string that is preceded with `>`
- `[^>.]*`  - matches zero or more (to match 1 or more use `+`) chars other than `>` and `.`
- `(?=[.]mainpattern)` -  a positive lookahead requiring the presence of a `.` and `mainpattern` after it right after the consuming (preceding) subpattern.

Answer (score 0):

As @WiktorStribiżew answered you can use regex.
For uniq list you need only add `sort` and `uniq` like:

```
pcregrep -o '(?<=>).*?(?=\.mainpattern)' *.txt | sort | uniq
```